# Cut connection if VPN down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

How can I effectively cut my Internet connection as soon as my VPN is down, avoiding my leaking my actual IP address?

I have tried creating a rule in Gufw to just allow traffic to my newly assigned VPN IP address (see [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1496473)) but I have no access to the Internet content.

Answer (score 0):

u might be able to do that using a packet manager. i used iptables (linux) u can create rule in in which all outbound/inbound packets will be routed through a specific IP